# push.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ratchet-2, push.js

When I click a link on my page the URL updates and I see the correct page content flash momentarily, then the content of the previous page takes hold. This only appears to happen when I use the data-transition attribute. The same problem occurs both in Chrome emulate mode or using Xcode emulator.

In Chrome's console I get this Uncaught TypeError on line 373 of push.js

I stripped two pages down to basics to try to troubleshoot and am pasting one of them below. (the second page is the same only linking to one.html with diff text)

Any idea why the previous page contents reload? (as I said the URL updates -- a refresh displays correct content)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test one</title>

    <!-- Sets initial viewport load and disables zooming  -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

    <!-- Makes your prototype chrome-less once bookmarked to your phone's home screen -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <!-- Include the compiled Ratchet CSS -->
    <link href="css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Include the compiled Ratchet JS -->
    <script src="js/ratchet.js"></script>
    <script src="js/push.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <header class="bar bar-nav">
    <h1 class="title">one</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
<a href="two.html" data-transition="slide-in">go to two</a>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't think push.js is an actual file, it's a concept. don't include it as a reference like you're doing in your head..?

Comment: That did the trick. Just a very fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: @ferr, push.js is more than a concept. Its a separate file in the [sources](https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/tree/master/js) along with toggle and others. They are aggregated in the ratchet.js build, but if you were actively modifying the ratchet source for some custom functionality you would import push.js and others for your debug builds.